# [PHP,AJAX,JS]403 forbiddeneven after chmod

Tags: php, ajax

I have ran into a problem. When my script calls a file `"js/chat.js"`
My host returns a "403" error,I have used cPanel's file manager to chmod to 777 to test,but still the same problem persists. Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What did you chmod to 777?  The directory js?  The file chat.js?

Comment: @user2182349 the /htdocs folder and all subfolders

Comment: @NicholasAgner even though it's a bad idea, for test purposes you might as well use `chmod -R 777 htdocs` (note the recursive flag)

Comment: @user2182349 Well I am using a host. Not sure if cPanel or byethost allows command line

Comment: It would help if you posted the code which is requesting the file - for example the script tag.

Comment: Visit here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4Aem-ixyExxZUtnOVp2QVhJY0k&usp=sharing

(This is not my project,its software called "AJAX-Chat" by blueimp